# Copying my local git repository directory should result in the same status message, right?

Tags: git

I have a git repository on my Mac in the directory `~/Documents/Source/ThingaMeIOS`. In that local repository if I run the `git status` command I see nothing outstanding:

> $ git status
>   On branch master
>   Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
>   nothing to commit, working tree clean

If I go up a directory and copy my local git repository (`cp -r ThingaMeIOS TestFlightThingaMeIOS`) and then swap to the newly copied local repository and re-run the `git status` command I do have outstanding changes:

> $ git status
>   On branch master
>   Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
>   Changes not staged for commit:
>    (use "git add/rm ..." to update what will be committed)
>    (use "git checkout -- ..." to discard changes in working directory)
>
> deleted:    Frameworks/HockeySDK.embeddedframework/HockeySDK.framework/Headers
>     typechange: Frameworks/HockeySDK.embeddedframework/HockeySDK.framework/HockeySDK
>     deleted:    Frameworks/HockeySDK.embeddedframework/HockeySDK.framework/Resources
>     deleted:    Frameworks/HockeySDK.embeddedframework/HockeySDK.framework/Versions/Current
>     deleted:    Frameworks/HockeySDK.embeddedframework/Resources/HockeySDKResources.bundle
>
> no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

Surely these two local repositories should be identical and should give identical responses to the `git status` command. What is going on?

Comment: where is your .git folder located? Can you post the dir structure of the project, might be some hidden files issues

Comment: I presume those files are hidden and thus won't be copied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a copy issue. I use tar for copying git versioned folders:

`cd /path/to/source; tar cvf - . | (cd /path/to/destination; tar xvf -)`

Supports hidden files and symlinks.
Very reliable - never had copy issues with this.

Comment: That worked a treat - though it took me a while to see that I'd typed `tar xvf - .` instead of `tar xvf -` for that second `tar` command, which did not work.

Comment: @dumbledad exactly. Glad I could help :)

Comment: Both answers look great, and I love the simplicity of `cp -R`, but it appears [this one's faster](http://superuser.com/a/985080/166855)(!) so I'll mark this one as the answer

Comment: Thanks for the additional info about cp vs tar

Comment: Although [digging further](http://stackoverflow.com/a/316247/575530) `cp` is quicker than `tar` for small numbers of huge files, while `tar` wins for large numbers of small files, and I guess the typical git repository is the latter.

Comment: I think so too. Thx for the info!

Answer (score 2):

"Typechange" occurs when (and only when) something was a symbolic link and is no longer, or vice versa.  So within your repository there were some symlinks that got copied as regular files.  Oddly, `-r` is no longer documented, but `-R` *is* documented as copying symlinks without trying to follow them.  On FreeBSD, `-r` and `-R` act the same, but on MacOS `-r` and `-R` behave differently, with `-r` copying the target of the link.

For whatever reason, copying the target of the link seems to be what resulted in deletions (this is surprising: I'd expect added files).

Comment: `cp -R <old> <new>` worked a treat, thank you. Do you know where we should report the missing `-r` in the Mac bash `cp` documentation?

Comment: @dumbledad: No idea where to report it, or whether anyone cares. The `scp` command has a (documented) lowercase `-r` that always follows symlinks. I imagine this causes confusion, since it certainly confused me :-) (I'm used to the old 4.2BSD lowercase-r-only variant of `cp`). I generally use `tar` myself to copy trees, although on the Mac there is also `ditto` which preserves HFS-specific extras. Mostly I just try to avoid copying trees in the first place, or hide it in a script (I had one for syncing Mac itunes across machines, back before they iCloud-ed everthing).